# Stopping times of random walk with time dependent absorbing barriers

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I have a Bern$(p)$ random walk ($Y_i = 1$ with probability $p$ and Y_i = 0 with $1-p$) with two absorbing boundaries, $A: Y^i \leq t_i$ and $B:Y^i \geq d_i-t_i$. Now, both $d_i$ and $t_i$ are evolving with time. $d_i$ is a simple affine function of $i$ (say $d_i = i+c$), but I want to choose $t_i$ such that $\mathbb{P}[\tau_A > \tau_B] = \delta$. I.e. I want to ensure quick absorption, but I want the probability that $A$ absorbs to be at least $1-\delta$. I want to do this by adjusting the $t_i$ parameters.

Is this a super tricky monster problem? I was hoping there would exist some kind of optimal sequential hypothesis testing threshold theorem that I could use :p

Answer (score 1):

Setting $X^i=Y^i - \frac{1}{2} d_i$ and $g_i=\frac{1}{2}d_i - t_i$ gives you $A : X^i\leq -g_i$ and $B : X^i\geq g_i$.

you can rewrite :
$X^i = x+\sum_{l=1}^i \xi_i$ where $\xi_i$ are i.i.d r.v. taking in your case $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ values with proba $p$ and $1-p$

If I choose $\mu$ such that $pe^{\frac{\mu}{2} }+(1-p)e^{-\frac{\mu}{2}}=1$, $Z^i=e^{\mu X^i}$ is a martingale.

I have using stopping theorem and the fact that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_A>\tau_B)=\delta$

choosing $g_i \equiv g$ a constant

$$\mathbb{E}[Z^{\min(\tau^A,\tau^B)}] =  e^{-\mu g}(1-\delta)+\delta e^{\mu g}=e^{\mu x}$$

or written in an other form:

$$\delta =\frac{e^{\mu x}-e^{-\mu g}}{e^{\mu g}-e^{-\mu g}}$$

Going back to your case, you are looking for $t_i = \frac{i}{2} - g$ where $g$ is a constant.

Comment: Wow that is pretty slick, I will attempt to digest this asap

Comment: I think there's a lot of typo's actually...

Comment: please edit or tell me so I correct them where you see errors. I assume your bernouilli takes +1 and -1 values and $x=Y^0-0.5c$

Comment: They're actually taking values +1 and 0. Will attempt to digest the rest a bit more, maybe it'll become obvious what to change.

Comment: Honestly, I'll need to read up more on the theory before grasping this. Will favorite it and come back and accept when I have. But thanks a lot for the answer, it really highlighted what I needed.